# How to manage GRUB when there are multiple drives and multiple OS releases

Tags: linux, multi-boot, grub

I have a system with 6 internal, and two permanently-attached USB3 external hard drives.  I also have (at the moment) 5 different OS-es installed (counting 1 Windows 10 install).  I'm having trouble maintaining this, and having trouble getting help from the documentation I can find.

The main problem is that right now GRUB is presenting a list of choices that I know is inaccurate.  Specifically, none say they have an Ubuntu 22.04, but there is one, and it is not the default.  The drive it is on shows as holding 20.04 in the boot menu.  This in spite of my doing a grub-install to each of them, and doing update-grub.

I could use any help, but the specific questions I have are:

1. what does install-grub actually do?  Details, please.
2. What is actually changed when I do grub-update, and why is that result not showing up in the boot menus?  When I run it, it reports finding the 22.04, but I do not see that reflected in any boot menu, even when I have the BIOS boot from all the drives it can.
3. What is the best way to organize /boot /boot/grub and /boot/efi when I have a mix of Debian- and RedHat-related distros?  Right now, each distro has its own copy of them, internal to the / filesystem.  And how to make the transition.
4. How can I tell that it is set up properly -- especially since there's at best a weak connection between what the BIOS report and what I see in GRUB and from lsblk(8)

Failing that, I would like to have a recommended arrangement for multiple-drives and multiple operating systems.  Links to clear documentation appreciated.

Not part of this question, but when I'm all done I am hoping to restore the Windows boot manager to /dev/sda, which contains all the Windows stuff and only the Windows stuff.  But I goofed some time ago and did an grub-install onto it.  The goal was to keep a separation between the Windows and Linux worlds.

Comment: Incorrect strategy in my opinion. I use Virtual Machines for this and have more than a dozen Windows and Linux systems. It is all really easy to port to a new machine.

Comment: Following up on @John, I would suggest setting up kvm as a hypervisor and loading OS’es from there. Dual-booting is easy. Configuring 5+ operation systems and managing the boot loader is much more difficult.

Comment: While not disagreeing with the previous comments I'll address the situation here: If your Ubuntu 22.04 is in charge of Grub then it should show up simply as "Ubuntu". Other installations' bootloaders should show other info, namely the release/version but not the one actually in control. Keep in mind the last installed OS usually takes control but it may not, you decide what boots by default at UEFI settings > Boot menu. Then, once selected the intended entry just run update-grub to add any new OS. Understanding this you understand everything you need to know about your complex system.

Comment: I understand about half of the comments.  Specific problems: I use the KVM acronym for my Keybord-Video-Mouse switch that allows my desk to see any of the machines.  What were you referring to?  I don't know where to find UEFI -> Settings -> Boot Menu.   Is that something in your machine's BIOS?  Or an option GRUB shows?  And the big quesion: if I follow the advice to use virtual machines, can they nevertheless share data?  I would need them all to have access to my 12TiB raid array, among other things..

Comment: One question per post please. You can post more than once, so long as they are different questions, but each post should have a single question that needs answered.